# Does analytic isomorphism imply local isomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, birational-geometry, formal-schemes

If $ \mathfrak{p} $ is a (not necessarily closed) point of a variety $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $, and $ \mathfrak{q} $ is a (not necessarily closed) point of a variety $ \operatorname{Spec}(B) $ such that $ (\mathfrak{p}, \operatorname{Spec}(A)) $ is analytically isomorphic to $ (\mathfrak{q}, \operatorname{Spec}(B)) $, then are there neighborhoods $ U \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ and $ V \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(B) $ such that $ \mathfrak{p} \in U $ and $ q \in V $ are such that $ U \cong V $?  Namely does analytic isomorphism of two affine varieties imply that they are birational?  We can assume that we are over a field of characteristic zero if that simplifies things.  Also if we assume that $ \mathfrak{p} $ and $ \mathfrak{q} $ are closed points, then does that change anything?

I do not know of any counterexamples to this assertion, but I may not have looked in the right places or thought of something clear.  If it is the case that I have not done my due diligence then I will gladly take the question down.  My intuition is that since the completion depends very much on local behavior that by looking at the germs around $ \mathfrak{p} $ and $ \mathfrak{q} $ one might be able to equate the two concepts.  However, I was hasty in assuming this and when asked why these two concepts were equivalent, I could not give a convincing enough answer.  If someone knows of a counterexample or a proof then I would be grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: No, take two $k$-points on two smooth curves of different genus. Both complete local rings are $k[[t]]$ and yet the curves are not birational.

Comment: However, there is a way to make intuition right. For excellent rings (such as rings of functions of varieties), we can find neighborhoods $U$ of $\mathfrak p$ and $V$ of $\mathfrak q$ in the sense of the Nisnevich topology (hence of étale topology) so that $U\cong V$. This is a consequence (or a reinterpretation) of Artin's approximation theorem: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CAT