# For what properties $ (\mathcal{P}) $ (if any) does $ (\mathcal{P}) $ + analytic isomorphism imply birationality?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, formal-schemes

In general if $ \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ and $ \mathfrak{q} \in \operatorname{Spec}(B) $ are two (not necessarily closed) points such that $ (\mathfrak{p}, \operatorname{Spec}(A)) $ and $ (\mathfrak{q}, \operatorname{Spec}(B)) $ are analytically isomorphic, then this does not in general imply that $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ and $ \operatorname{Spec}(B) $ are birational (see [Does analytic isomorphism imply local isomorphism?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434286/does-analytic-isomorphism-imply-local-isomorphism)).  Piotr Achinger kindly [provided](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434286/does-analytic-isomorphism-imply-local-isomorphism#comment1118596_434286) the example of two smooth, closed points on curves with different genera.  The curves are analytically isomorphic at these points, but the curves are not birational.

What properties $ (\mathcal{P}) $ of the varieties $ \operatorname{Spec}(A), \operatorname{Spec}(B) $, and points $ \mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{q} $ such that analytic isomorphism and property $ (\mathcal{P}) $ implies birationality?

I suspect that one property $ (\mathcal{P}) $ that implies the result is the following one if both $ A $ and $ B $ are non-singular.  Let us denote the completion of $ A $ (respectively $ B $) at $ \mathfrak{p} $ (respectively $ \mathfrak{q} $) by $ \widehat{A} $ (respectively $ \widehat{B} $) and the analytic isomorphism from $ \widehat{A} $ to $ \widehat{B} $ by $ \phi $ ($ \phi: \widehat{A} \to \widehat{B} $).  In general if $ \phi_{\ast}: \Omega_{\widehat{B}/k} \to \Omega_{\widehat{A}/k} $, then $ \phi_{\ast} $ will only be an isomorphism of $ \Omega_{\widehat{B}/k} $ with $ \Omega_{\widehat{A}/k} $ and not necessarily an isomorphism of $ \Omega_{B/k} $ with $ \Omega_{A/k} $.  However, assume that in addition
\begin{align*}
\phi_{\ast}(\Omega_{B/k}) & \cong \Omega_{A/k} \\
\phi^{-1}_{\ast}(\Omega_{A/k}) & \cong \Omega_{B/k} 
\end{align*}
I believe that if the above isomorphisms hold then this is a sufficient property $ (\mathcal{P}) $.

This is not true for the case of two curves with different genera.  If $ A $ is the ring $ k[t] $ and $ B $ is the ring $ k[x,y]/\langle y^{2}-x^{3} \rangle $, then the morphism $ \phi_{\ast} $ sends $ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} $ to $ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(t^{3/2}) \notin \Omega_{k[t]/k} $.

The reason I suspect that this works is the following.  If $ \delta_{1},\dotsc,\delta_{n} $ generate $ \Omega_{B/k} $ as a $ B $-module, then
\begin{align*}
a_{1} \delta \circ \phi(a_{2})+\delta \circ \phi(a_{1}) a_{2} &= \delta \circ \phi(a_{1}a_{2}) \\
&= \delta(\phi(a_{1})\phi(a_{2})) \\
&= \phi(a_{1}) \delta \circ \phi(a_{2})+\delta \circ \phi(a_{1}) \phi(a_{2}).
\end{align*}
This shows that the $ A $-module structure on $ \Omega_{A/k} $ with respect to the basis $ \{\phi_{\ast}(\delta_{1}),\dots,\phi_{\ast}(\delta_{n})\} $ sends $ a \cdot \phi_{\ast}(\delta_{i}) $ to $ \phi(a) \phi_{\ast}(\delta_{i}) $.  By applying the same argument to $ \phi^{-1}_{\ast} $, and then using the fact that $ \phi^{-1}_{\ast} \circ \phi_{\ast}(\Omega_{B/k}) \cong \Omega_{B/k} $, the $ B $-module structure on $ \Omega_{B/k} $ which sends $ (b,\delta_{i}) $ to $ b \delta_{i} $ and which sends $ (b,\delta_{i}) $ to $ \phi \circ \phi^{-1}(b) \delta_{i} $ are the same.  Therefore $ \phi $ is an isomorphism from $ A $ onto $ B $.

If this does work, then I suspect that there may be other properties which do not require as much and still imply the desired result.  The overall question is interesting as it relates to uniruledness among other things (see [What is the obstruction to uniruledness being uninteresting?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434130/what-is-the-obstruction-to-uniruledness-being-uninteresting) and the current resolution of this question).

Comment: Your link to [Does analytic isomorphism imply local isomorphism?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434286/does-analytic-isomorphism-imply-local-isomorphism) goes to @D.-C.Cisinski's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434286/does-analytic-isomorphism-imply-local-isomorphism#comment1118597_434286).  Was that intentional? \\ Also, what does "the current resolution of this question [[What is the obstruction to uniruledness being uninteresting?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434130/what-is-the-obstruction-to-uniruledness-being-uninteresting)]" mean?

Comment: Thank you @LSpice.  That was not intentional.  I believe that I have fixed this.  As to the remark "the current resolution of this question" this refers to the fact that the mere existence of a derivation may imply that $ \widehat{A}^{\widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}}}[[g/h]] \cong \widehat{A} $.  The ring $ \widehat{A}^{\widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}}} $ is the completion of a ring $ B $ at a prime of $ \mathfrak{q} $.  However, we do not know a' priori that $ B[t] \cong A $.  If we could add this property $ (\mathcal{P}) $ for certain derivations, then we would know that the underlying variety is uniruled.

Comment: The existence of $ g,h $ is the only other thing which is not known.  However, assuming that such $ g,h $ do exist I give an argument in that question that shows that if property $ (\mathcal{P}) $ also holds, then the variety is uniruled.  The resolution to the question I linked was that the p"r"oof that the mere existence of a derivation does not hold because analytic isomorphism does not imply birationality.